# Prototype - iPhone screen sized Keynote Slide (Resize slide)

Tags: keynote

I watched WWDC 2014 Session -223 where they explained how to make quick and interactive iOS app prototypes using keynote. As shown in the image below, they made the slide to look like iOS screen. however it wasnt explained how they did it. Is there anyway to resize slides?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the size of your slides using the **Custom Slide Size…** option.

An iPhone 5's screen resolution is: 640×1136

Other iPhone screen sizes are available on http://www.iphoneresolution.com.

[image: Custom Slide Size]

Comment: Thanks Graham. That worked in desktop version. The web version of Keynote doesnt have that setting available.